# Sqlite3 data convert to python for real time

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, time

I read the data from the sqlite3, I need to use the 'last_visit_time', but the data is '12979085322912388L',I just use python

```
import datetime,time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t1.py", line 21, in <module>
    print time.gmtime(long(12979085330693664L))
ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

....I can't use ctime, gmtime.... range limitation, so how can I translate it to the real time, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1297908532.2912388)
datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 17, 2, 8, 52, 291239)
```

If the `last_visit_time` corresponds to 2011-02-17, then you can use

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(last_visit_time / 1e7)
datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 17, 2, 8, 52, 291239)
```

Comment: But I don't know the last_visit_time, so is it possible to extract time form 12979085330693664L, without other information?

Comment: If you have no further information, you have to guess. But I don't think there are many other alternatives. Do you have more timestamp information in the database? If you convert other timestamps using my method, do you get logical results? (such as no times older than the age of the website, no times newer than now, etc.)

Comment: 12979231706879288L the latest timestamp, just now, then 12979231436918790L maybe two minutes ago, but I can't guest....help me